# MenuItem click event targeted at render

Tags: reactjs

Im upset and I'm hating React because I make one step ahead on two behind.
Now the problem is the method onCLick event of a MenuItem that is targeted at render time and not when I effectively click the menu.

MenuItem is inside a Drawer component:

```
<Drawer
  open={this.props.state_open_list_dash}
  openSecondary={true}
  docked={false}
>
```

with:

```
 <MenuItem 
    onClick={ this.handleChangeDash() }> Menu Name 
 </MenuItem>
```

In the constructor:

```
this.handleChangeDash = this.handleChangeDash.bind(this);
```

and then:

```
handleChangeDash ()
{     
   console.log(20);
}
```

The "20" on console is printed (3 times) at app refresh and (2 times) when the Drawer is opened due to an click event that change state_open_list_dash.

I have ended the ideas. Searching on web I've not found anyone with this problem so Im worried.

THanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're invoking the function `onClick={ this.handleChangeDash() }` at the runtime.

Change it to:

```
 <MenuItem 
    onClick={ this.handleChangeDash }> Menu Name 
 </MenuItem>
```

or you can make an arrow function like so

```
 <MenuItem 
    onClick={ () => this.handleChangeDash() }> Menu Name 
 </MenuItem>
```

`onClick` will automatically invoke it when the event will happen.

Comment: Thank you. This resolve the first step of the problem because to simplify the code in the question, I removed the reason why I was calling the method with bracket. Looking on google, I have just resolved the second part of the problem with the syntax onClick { () => this.handleChangeDash(parameter) }

Comment: ok then use it like `<MenuItem onClick={ () => this.handleChangeDash(dash['id']) }>`